# Danish letters in lmodern and cm-super

Tags: fonts, scandinavian-letters

Generally, the *lmodern* fonts look a tad nicer than *cm-super*. For the special Danish characters, å (lower-case) and Å (upper-case), however, *lmodern* does not look that well.

Here are two images with the Danish special characters typeset using *cm-super* and *lmodern*.

**cm-super:**
[image: Danish characters with cm-super]

**lmodern:**
[image: Danish characters with lmodern]

As you might be able to see, the serifs on *lmodern* are slightly curved and the kerning between 'ø' and 'å' is better than in *cm-super*.

But there is one big downside: the ring above the lower-case 'å' is drawn with a too heavy stroke and the ring not centered above the 'a' in *lmodern*. For the upper-case 'Å' the ring also looks akward (even though it seems to be centered correctly here).

You probably need to be Danish to take notice of these small differences but have anybody else (Danes?) noticed this and is there a way to tweak the 'å' and 'Å' to look as nice as the rest of the *lmodern* fonts?

## EDIT

After receiving the comment from @Sverre I must agree that the size, circular form and stroke of the ring used above both the lower case 'å' and the upper case 'Å' is fine.

So the remaining problem in *lmodern* wrt the Scandinavian letter 'å' IMHO is the placement of the ring above the lower case 'å'. I find it placed too far to the right and too high above the 'a'. It needs to be lowered a bit and to be (almost) centered over the top curve of the 'a'.

I suggest modifying the 'å' something like this:

[image: Modified 'å']
*lmodern 'å' – modified*

Here is the original *lmodern* 'å' for comparison:

[image: Original 'å']
*lmodern 'å' (original)*

And here is the 'å' of *Times*:

[image: 'å' of Times]
*Times 'å'*

Comment: You don't need to be Danish to care about these letters, since they are widely used outside of Danish. That aside, I don't think the ring above the lower case ``a`` is too thick. I've compared with other fonts, and it's the thin ring used in ``cs-super`` that's the odd man out here. I find nothing wrong with the upper case ``Å`` (could you specify what the problem is, beyond calling it "awkward"?).

Comment: @Sverre You are right, 'æøå' is used in Norway and 'å' in Sweden. Like for the lower-case 'å' I found the ring over the upper case Å to thick – but after your comment I have reconsidered (and studied a bunch of other fonts) so I agree with you. The ring is nice and circular with a fitting thickness. However, I still find the ring over the lower-case 'å' misplaced. It is too far to the right and also needs to be lowered a bit. Do you agree?

Comment: @Sverre Please see edit.

Comment: Very well - I agree that the kerning of the ring in ``lmodern`` should be improved. But something puzzles me here. You're providing a "modified" ``lmodern`` letter ``å`` to suit your needs, but your question was "is there a way to tweak the 'å'?". But apparently, you already know how to do that ... ?

Comment: @Sverre No, I don't know how to properly fix the 'å'. The images above are simply... images. The modified 'å' was modified in Gimp to show what I believe is wrong and in what direction the ring should be moved. So the 'å' in my LaTeX documents in lmodern still looks as in the original image. Unless somebody else has a different suggestion, I will contact the team as proposed in the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am right, this is the question "What should I do?". Here http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry is the information about the team working on Latin Modern. Every suggestion will help them to improve the fonts.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. :-) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction which I hadn't been able to find myself.